# filling an object from list using Lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda

I m new to Lambda and from a list of object want to filter a list and an individual object.

Two types are as below:

**Users**

```
 Id,Name,Password, EmailAddress
```

**Credentials**

```
Id,Password
```

Can you please guide me how from List I can fill a Credentials object selecting based on `name="Micheal"` and `EmailAddress="mich@domain.com"`

How I can get `List<credentials>` from `List<users>`

I highly appreciate your precious time and helping me out.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var credentials = userList.Where(e => e.Name == "Micheal" &&
                                      e.EmailAddress == "mich@domain.com")
                          .Select(e => new Credentials() 
                                 { Id = e.Id, Password = e.Password }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Esteban Elverdin, will it select complete list ?

Comment: @Toubi, yes, this will return a list of Credentials, if you want just one, use First() or FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 3):

```
  var credentials = 
     users.Where(u => u.name == "Michael" && u.EmailAddress == "mich@domain.com")
          .Select(u => new Credentials{ Password = u.Password, Id = u.Id })
          .ToList()
```

Do something like the above. This will give you a list of credential objects.